# Magento 2 : Price mismatch

Tags: magento2, product, price, reindex

In magento 2.4.2,
the admin catalog product has price 40 & in frontend also 40
but in '`catalog_product_entity_decimal`' the same product's price is 50.

Why so ?
What can be done to fix this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: What is the price on frontend?

Comment: Its 40 on the frontend

Comment: Can I look up the whole row that showing wrong price?

Comment: I figured the issue with usage of entity_id instead of row id.
Thankyou